# How to duplicate a list in Scheme x times?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am just starting to learn Scheme and using cons is a little confusing to me. I have a function `duplicate (s number)` where s is a list, and number is the number of times the list should be duplicated.

If I enter `(duplicate '(1 2) 3)`, the output should be `((1 2) (1 2) (1 2))`

My program looks like this, but when I run it, there is nothing in the output

```
(define (duplicate s number)
  (cond [(null? s) '()]
        [(> 0 number) (cons (list s) (duplicate s(- number 1)))] 
))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `s` is already a list. eg. `(1 2)`, `(list s)` will make it `((1 2))` also you are supposed to stop when `number` is zero, but you stop when the list is empty without ever changing the list.

Comment: @Sylwester How do you suggest I stop the program correctly then?

Comment: Well. I did write when `number` is `zero?` in my comment. Imagine what `(duplicate '(1 2) 0)` should do. Then Imagine that `(duplicate '(1 2) 2) ; ==> (cons '(1 2) (duplicate '(1 2) 1)`. Also it doesn't matter what `s` is. eg. `(duplicate #f 3) ;==> (#f #f #f)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want second input `n` become zero complete all list.
And we want output is a list so we use `cons`.

You can build your code by using minimum sample than add more complex data.

If input is `(duplicate x 0)` we want output is `'()`.

If input is `(duplicate x 1)` we want output is `'(x)`.

So your code should looks like this

```
(define (duplicate x n)
  (cond
    [(= n 0) '()]
    [else
     (cons x ...)]))
```

But we already know we want output is `'(x)` which is `(cons x '())`.
Obvious `'()` is `(duplicate x 0)`'s output. So we add `(duplicate x (- n 1))` in second condition.

```
#lang racket

(define (duplicate x n)
  (cond
    [(= n 0) '()]
    [else
     (cons x (duplicate x (- n 1)))]))


;;; TEST
(duplicate '() 0)
(duplicate '() 3)
(duplicate '() 5) ; '(() () () () ())
(duplicate '(1 2) 5) ; '((1 2) (1 2) (1 2) (1 2) (1 2))
```

Or you can think like this way.
We have employee help us copy document.

employee-1 : We give him a number than he minus 1 than order employee-2 do his job

employee-2 : He copy a document than send message to employee-3

employee-3 : He supervision finish or not (number become zero). If not finish send message to employee-1.

So we want something like this
finish? -> no -> minus-1 -> copy -> finish? -> no -> minus-1 -> ...

```
#lang racket

(define x 1)
(define result '())

(define (employee-1 n)
  (employee-2 (- n 1)))

(define (employee-2 n)
  (begin
    (set! result (cons x result))
    (employee-3 n)))

(define (employee-3 n)
  (if (= n 0)
      result
      (employee-1 n)))

;;; TEST
(employee-3 3) ; '(1 1 1)
```

Than we combine `employee-1` to `employee-3`

```
(define x 1)
(define result '())
; (define (employee-1 n) (employee-2 (- n 1)))

(define (employee-2 n)
  (begin
    (set! result (cons x result))
    (employee-3-v2 n)))

(define (employee-3-v2 n)
  (if (= n 0)
      result
      (employee-2 (- n 1))))

;;; TEST
(employee-3-v2 3) ; '(1 1 1)
```

We use function input replace define global variable. So we have to remove `set!` and change input parameter.

```
; (define x 1)
; (define result '())
; (define (employee-1 n) (employee-2 (- n 1)))

(define (employee-2-v2 n x result)
  (employee-3-v2 n x (cons x result)))

(define (employee-3-v2 n x result)
  (if (= n 0)
      result
      (employee-2-v2 (- n 1) x result)))

;;; TEST
(employee-3-v2 3 1 '()) ; '(1 1 1)
```

Than we combine `employee-2-v2` to `employee-3-v2`. Remember we have to change input parameter.

```
(define (employee-3-v3 n x result)
  (if (= n 0)
      result
      (employee-3-v3 (- n 1) x (cons x result))))

;;; TEST
(employee-3-v3 3 'x '()) ; '(x x x)
```

Now we want remove not necessary input parameter `result`.

```
(define (employee-3-v4 n x)
  (if (= n 0)
      '()
      (cons x (employee-3-v4 (- n 1) x))))

;;; TEST
(build-list 10 (λ (n) (employee-3-v4 n 'x)))

#|
output:

'(()
  (x)
  (x x)
  (x x x)
  (x x x x)
  (x x x x x)
  (x x x x x x)
  (x x x x x x x)
  (x x x x x x x x)
  (x x x x x x x x x))
|#
```